# Blender 2.8: How to select edges behind other edges when in numpad 1 mode

Tags: selection-tools

In a tutorial I am seeing the guy go into 'Mesh Mode' where he is able to select edges behind other edges.

However I am unable to do this in 2.8.

When I select it just selects the closest edge.

Comment: The closest edge to the mouse, or the closest edge to the camera?

Comment: the best solution to this problem is the border occlusion addon -- [download it here](https://github.com/Darcvizer/Border-Occlusion) [video how its works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RwrHI2Tj90)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be able to select occluded geometry you must enable the viewport option *X-Ray*.

Either use the button on the 3D View Header or press access the with <kbd>Z</kbd> key *Shading Pie Menu > Toggle X-Ray*.

[image]

Comment: As of 20190518 the x-ray option can be found under the viewport options (little arrow to the right of the shader options) but only in solid or wireframe mode (not lookdev or rendered). The x-ray symbol as shown in the answer above is not there anymore.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without changing the viewport drawing mode??

I'd love just a 'allow backface selection' toggle, I know where the verts are on the top of a box, seems silly to toggle the mode, select, then toggle it back for every selection.

Comment: You can toggle XRray from any viewport shading mode.

Comment: get the border occlusion addon and save your time